# Saving value after a refresh

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I'm passing a value 'name="idUser"' through a Form with POST from pageA to pageB.

Then in pageB I have a query that uses this value for different things, like select, updates, inserts,etc.

> Ej: 
>   $updateIDU=$_POST["idUser"];
>
> ## Select * from table where idUser = $updateIDU;

The pageB has a table in a Form that it can be updated (you can add values, with the form you send the values to the database).

After the information is updated to the database i refresh the page with this:

```
$link="LOCATION:pageB.php?ok=1";
header($link);
```

The problem is when i refresh the page with that method the querys for the tables crashes with errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: idUser in C:\wamp64\www\pageB.php

Can somebody help me fix my problem or is there another way to pass this value (ID) from pageA to pageB without losing it on refresh (updating the form-table)?

**Note** When I refresh the page (F5) the page dosen't show me any errors, but when I update the table (with the form) it does show me the error.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you set the post to a session if there's nothing being posted?

Comment: You need a session. http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: when you pass from pageA to pageB a table is displayed using the $_POST["idUser"] that was sent from pageA.
this table also has this idUser, what i did was to add this idUser in the table using the same name of the form from pageA (idUser)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Post you can set a cookie to retain data across all the pages. Set cookie using this:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
```

And then access them using this:

```
$_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

Comment: Cookies or sessions are a better solution.

Comment: the $value is going to be the $_POST? or how do i get the ID sent from the Form to the setcookie().
The thing i'm trying to do is, you have a search engine that it will list all of the users, when you press the button "information" it will redirect you to the pageB where is going to show the information using the userID the post sent

Comment: When the Post data from page A gets to page B, set the cookie from the post data. After the page refresh you will be able to access the data from the cookie, as it is stored in the user's browser.

Comment: I added the "setcookie("TestCookie", $_POST['idUser']);" at the begining of pageB.

And in my querys I used where idUser = $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];, but when i clic the "Update" button in my form it causes errors.
Undefined index: idUser in C:\wamp64\www\pageB.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: TestCookie in C:\wamp64\www\pageB.php on line 145

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hidden form field in page b , when ever user lands on page b update the form field .